# How can I create partitions on a SD card (mmc) at a firmware level

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

I want to prevent data corruption on an SD card by having a read only partition and a read/write partition.

SD card controllers don't respect partitions on the physical flash disk so normal partitions can still be corrupted if even one of them is write enabled.

Mmc seems to have firmware based partitioning available as a otp (one time programmable) option along with a firmware based read only flag.

However I have no idea how to actually create these partitions or read only flags.

Source: http://www.docfoc.com/120912-mic-emmc-partitioning-JM3b1